# Comparing Time in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two entity in mysql which are opening_hours and closing_hours. I stored them as a TIME For example:

```
opening_hours : 08:00:00
closing_hours : 17:30:00
```

I want to compare those with current time.

I am using moment.js to get current time.

```
current_time = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
```

It returns 18:13:42 for now.

I want to write; If current time bigger than opening_hours and smaller than closing_hours do sth.

Are there any way to without split ?

Comment: You should remove the `mysql` tag since the question is not MySQL related

Comment: @Gab sure......

Comment: Why do you need momentJs for that? JavaScript dates are numbers, so just subtract them from each other and see if you get a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in JavaScript are internally just numbers (the number of ticks from 1/1/1970, if I remember correctly). You don't need another library like momentJs or jQuery in order to find if one time is greater than another.

```
var date1 = new Date('01/01/2017 08:00:00');
var date2 = new Date('01/01/2017 17:30:00');
var difference = date2 - date1;
// difference is 34200000
```

Since you have a positive number, you know `date2` is greater than `date1`. If you need to go to the next day (in case it closes after midnight), you can just add a date to `date2`.

A better way to create the date variables may be through setting properties on the objects, but that is up to your use case.